# Winterbash Hats Are Behind Avatar (2018)

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018, avatar

I've not been in the SO community for very long, so I don't know if this is expected behaviour or not, but I have just unlocked my first 2 hats, and I have been playing around with moving them, but I have found that they appear behind my avatar, making them somewhat invisible. (See my avatar).

If this is expected behaviour, then I request that it be changed, otherwise, it's a bug that should hopefully not be too hard to fix.

---

Edit: apparently the badge is above my avatar for other users. Screenshots:

[image: Small]

*In the top bar*

[image: Large]

*In the winterbash pop-up*

---

Further edit: I tested this in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge, and it works as expected. Chrome version: Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (32-bit).

Comment: For me your hat is visible on top of your avatar

Comment: @Codeer Not for me. This is strange

Comment: Do you have a userscript/stylesheet which modifies the CSS somehow? How do other users' hats appear? What browser / OS are you using?

Comment: @Glorfindel I have disabled all my userscripts & darkmode add-ons, my browser is Chrome, I am using a Windows 7 Enterprise computer. Other users hats are also behind their avatars [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Comment: I see it as you describe! (firefox, ubuntu)

Comment: I see it above the avatar. Firefox 44, windows 10.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Tested in IE and it works. Editing question now.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Cleared cached data, but same as before.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl If you change the z-index of the hat or the avatar in the developer tools, can you make it work properly? Do your other hats also misbehave?

Comment: @AndrewMorton All my hats misbehave. I don't do any web development, but I'm trying to do as you suggest now

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nah sorry i just get lost in the developer console.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I keep Chrome in a VM so it doesn't touch my computer, but you should be able to right-click an element, choose "Inspect", find a "Styles" tab, and to "element.style" add `z-index: 999 !important` inside the braces. If you feel like it. (Also, the web site in your profile doesn't seem to do anything.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185218/discussion-between-artemis-fowl-and-andrew-morton).

Comment: Chrome what? What version? Please add this to the q

Comment: That is some nice koalaity assurance!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Version 70.0.3538.67 (Official Build) (32-bit)

Comment: I also see this in Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.17 (Official Build) beta (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Wow. Strange, very very strange.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and finally I found the reason after some investigations.

For me, the Chrome addon Midlight Lizard caused this issue.

For those who do not have Midlight Lizard installed, you can try to pause Greasemonkey, Stylish and so on.